# Why isn't Jenkins update center showing latest plugin versions?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have the Update Site under Plugin Manager/Advanced tab set to:
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json

Im not using the update center plugin.

When i try to update the declarative pipeline plugin, i have version 1.3.2, it only allows me to downgrade to 1.3.

I need to update it to 1.3.4.1 to clear a security issue. I've read manually installing plugins is risky. Why cant i see the latest plugin versions in the update center ?

Thanks

Comment: I have jenkins version 2.89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon. That plugin technically requires Jenkins 2.121.1 or later, but I recommend you upgrade to Jenkins 2.166 (Latest, stable at the time of this post). Then, your URL might work, but it’s best to use https when you are getting updates.

Use...

https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json

OR

https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json

The version you are looking for is in the .json file. I verified after upgrading my own Jenkins server that “Pipeline: Declarative” is version 1.3.4.1 in the Plugin Manager.

Comment: I updated jenkins to 2.166 and now i can see the latest plugin versions. Also switched to the https update sites. Glad it was a simple thing. Thanks for your help!